# Read hashmap with inner array of objects in java

Tags: java, hashmap

This is a result I get from a hashmap in java. How do we read this and extract value1 and value2 and put them inside another hash map? And only one array of object inside.

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "desc": {
                "value1": "",
                "value2 ""
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the method tried,

```
HashMap result = (HashMap) response.get("result");
HashMap desc = (HashMap) result.get("desc");
map.put("value1", desc.get("value1"));
map.put("value2", desc.get("value2"));
```

Comment: `response.get("result")` isn't a Map, it's a List

Comment: @azro , do u konw how to achive this? I need to get value1 and value2 from this. There is only one array of object inside.

Comment: Achieve what ? We don't know the initial class of `response`. Cas it into a List instead of a Map, and use it like a list

Comment: @azro this is the type of response ----->  HashMap<String, Object> response

Comment: And what about casting it to list and use like a list then ?

Comment: Right, will do like that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `List` level

```
List<Object> result = (List<Object>) response.get("result");
HashMap<String,Object> item = (HashMap<String,Object>) result.get(0);
HashMap<String,String> desc = (<String,String>) item.get("desc");
map.put("value1", desc.get("value1"));
map.put("value2", desc.get("value2"));
```

Comment: Just to understand,  response.get("result").get(0).get("serial").get("id") @azro is this wrong?

Comment: @Nickjonas Does it raise an error ? If you don't cast, you have `Object` and you can't call the `get` methods